# How can we print a list of numbers taken as [1,2,3,4,5] in a column one by one such that the output should be as 1 2 3 4 5

Tags: python

i had written a piece of code expecting the output as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

but i am unable to get that with my code
for num in numlist:
print(num)
print(num,end=' ')
1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5

```
for num in numlist:
print(num)
```

print(num,end=' ')
1
2
3
4
5
5
can i know when i am executing it separately without indentation i am getting 5 5 two time line by line
And also what if i wanted to get the output as
1

2

3

4

5

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

Comment: If you want to print each item once, why would you write a loop that has two `print()` statements?  That will (obviously) print each num twice...

Comment: `print(*numlist, sep='\n')` will print them in a column.

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension to get a list of strings, and then use join to get a string and print it.

```
strlist = [str(x) for x in numlist] 
outstr = "\n".join(strlist) 
print(outstr)
```

Comment: yes but the wanted output is to print the numbers one by one in a coloumn

Comment: You are correct, I read a single line. Fixed it! @SailakshmiReddy